# PHP regular expression only checking the first character in the input

Tags: php, regex

I am making a login system for a website that I am doing.
I have only limited experience of using regular expressions, and for some reason it isn't working.
The code in question is:

```
if (!(preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+/",$username)&&(strlen($username)>=4) && 
strlen($username)<=25))
{
      return 4;
}
```

The length check works correctly, but the character check doesn't.
It is supposed to check to make sure than `$username` only contains letters, numbers _ and space.
It seems to only check the first character, and after that, anything goes!

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use anchor around your regex `^..regex..$`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the "first in line" `^` and "end of line" `$` modifiers

For instance:

```
 preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+$/",$username)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the following regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9_ ]+$/i
```

Regular expression

```
^             # the beginning of the string
 [a-z0-9_ ]+  # any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9', '_', ' ' (1 or more times)
$             # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Perhaps not as this is PHP and you want to keep anything locale out.

Comment: `\w` may not be a good idea. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php): "*A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by `\w`.*".